# Javascript conditional in Rails with Turbolinks?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set a conditional for turbolinks pages - where different parts of the page fade depending what part of the site they are on.

I'm using a class in specific links to let me know when I want the alternate behaviour - so the links with class 'commentlink' will trigger a fade of the '.commentBit' div, but the rest of the site will trigger '#mainPage' to fade.

I can't seem to get the following conditional to work, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
hasBeenClicked = false
$(document).on( 'click', '.commentlink', ->
  hasBeenClicked = true
  )

$(document).on 'page:fetch', ->
  if hasBeenClicked
    $('.commentBit').fadeOut 'fast'
  else
    $('#mainPage').fadeOut 'fast'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wrong things are fading out when you click on links, it may be because you are not resetting `hasBeenClicked` after each fade.

If you click a `.commentLink`, the `.commentBit` will properly fade out, but then because `hasBeenClicked` is still true, any other link click will prompt the same behaviour.

Reset `hasBeenClicked` to false after fading out `.commentBit`.